# c++ - "%" gets added to the standard output

Tags: c++, clang++

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout<<"hello";
        return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
/Users/aj/Documents/c++ programs % clang++ prog.cpp
/Users/aj/Documents/c++ programs % ./a.out         
hello%
```

Does anyone have any idea why an additional character "%" gets appended to the standard output ?

I am using clang++ version 13

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: The `%` seems to be from your terminal. Try  `cout<<"hello\n";`, the output of your code will be only a single line then, all the rest is not from your code

Comment: What is the `xxx % ` part of the command?

Comment: I believe the `%` thing indicates the lack of `\n` after the last line.

Comment: btw you should be more precise. When you write "The output is" then not all of it is output

Comment: @NathanOliver I have just hidden the file path

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't understand ? that IS the entire output

Comment: and the output is not `helloxxx %` ?

Comment: no, that is the command you used to compile and run and the output. I am being a little pedantic here, but as the quesiton is just about that details it does matter

Answer (score 2):

See how there's a % sign before your compile and execute commands? That your shell inserting it. Try adding a newline at the end of your string so that the shell's percent sign doesn't collide with your string.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout<<"hello"<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: consensus nowadays is that '\n' is better than endl

Comment: Yea I observe it, but why all of a sudden it's happening ? never happened before and is there any better fix than to add endl ?

Comment: @AjaySabarish -- the best fix is to add `'\n '`. Formally, writing text to an output stream without a newline at the end results in undefined behavior.

Comment: `'\n'` says to start a new line. `std::endl` says to start a new line **and** to flush the output. Unless you have a particular reason for flushing, don't do it. At the end of the program the standard output streams get flushed, so you don't need it there. `std::cout` gets flushed when you request input from `std::cin`, so you don't need it there. Pretty much the only time it's useful is if your program is crashing and you want to see all of the output up to the point of the crash. But in that case, writing to `std::cerr` is a better choice because it gets flushed immediately.